# Share objects between django views / global objects

Tags: python, django

Often in Django I want to create and configure some object at startup, and have it available everywhere. For example a third-party API client.

So when django starts I want to do this:

```
from some.thirdparty import ThirdPartyClient
from django.conf import settings
...
my_thirdparty_client = ThirdPartyClient(configstring=settings.SOME_CONFIG_ITEM)
```

And then in a view somewhere I want to do this:

```
from somewhere import my_thirdparty_client

def whatever(request):
    my_thirdparty_client.do_stuff()
    my_thirdparty_client.do_even_more_stuff()
```

Obviously I understand that I can instantiate the client at the start of the view, but if initalizing the instance is expensive I don't want to do it on every request.

What is the idiomatic Django way of creating these kinds of objects that I want to share between views?

Comment: Why not just create a global object on top of the view file?

Comment: @xyres I guess I'm looking for the semi-official way to do it (that will be least surprising for other devs)

Answer (score 3):

> What is the idiomatic Django way of creating these kinds of objects that I want to share between views?

Django has nothing to do with this problem.
You just need to use the design pattern which is called - [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

I prefer to use a metaclass to implement this pattern in Python
 but there are other ways too.

```
class SingletonMetaclass(type):

    _instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        assert not (args or kwargs), 'Singleton should not accept arguments'

        if isinstance(cls._instance, cls):
            return cls._instance
        else:
            cls._instance = super(SingletonMetaclass, cls).__call__()
            return cls._instance


class ThirdPartyClient(metaclass=SingletonMetaclass):

    def __init__(self):
        self.configstring = settings.SOME_CONFIG_ITEM
```

In order to initialize your client, you could use [AppConfig.ready](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) method.
It will be run only once when your Django app is ready to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Yes it would need to be a singleton, but I would need to put the name somewhere, as I don't have access to the third party library providing the client, I would have to make a singleton subclass of it - fine - but where should I define it? In a specific django app? Should I make an app containing all my singletons? Flask deals with this through it's "extensions", I wondered where django devs expect to find these objects.

Comment: @jsj "I would have to make a singleton subclass of it "
 it's not necessary. You can initialize an instance in your `ready` method and assign it to somewhere. After that, you can just import a function that will know how to return this instance.
"where should I define it? In a specific django app?"
You can initialize the instance in your root app's (project) method `ready` as I provided in my answer.

Comment: @jsj But if you have some specific django app and this client belongs to it then just initialize it in this specific django app's method `ready`.

Comment: @jsj instead of saying thanks, mark my answer as a solution to show it to other developers.

Comment: Hi @GregEremeev its a long time ago but I like you answer but I need some clarification. What do you mean with "initialize an instance and assign it to somewhere"? I can instantiate the class in the app.ready method but where to assign this instance to? I cant get my head around that part. Also: why do singleton classes dont use arguments?